# Fetching images from Tweets with Tweetie?

Tags: javascript, php, twitter

I am using this great and very simple script called [Tweetie](https://github.com/sonnyt/Tweetie) to display tweets from a hashtag on my website.

If you look at `tweetie.js` on line 38 you will see that the script displays a link when there is an image attached to a tweet. I was wondering if it is possible to display the actual image instead with `<img src="url">`.
The link it is creating looks like this: `http://t.co/yELrAQseih`

Comment: I have looked at this topic, but I am not very good at these things, so I don't really understand how to add it to Tweetie. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15594130/how-to-embed-twitter-tweets-how-to-catch-images-from-tweets-urls-and-display?rq=1

Comment: what have you "TRIED", not looked. 
Just get started. Without trying, you will go nowhere

Comment: Well, I don't really know where to start to be honest with you. I know it probably have something to do with media_url in the Twitter API https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/entities-in-twitter-objects#media But I don't know how to implement that into this code that I have.

Comment: Here is what I've got so far. Sorry it is in Norwegian, but you can see that page fetches tweets based on the #e3sistestopp hashtag. The tweets with images in them has a link at the end of the tweet. http://sistestopp.com/om/