# Getting URL's from string

Tags: php, regex

I have a string containing a HTML document and I want to extract all URL's from it.
I tried this:

```
preg_match_all('/(http:\/\/){1}.{1,}\..{1,}/', $html_document /* a valid document, containing a lot of links*/, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

But instead of array containing all links, I get parts of HTML code.
What's wrong with my code?

Comment: `{1,}` allows for "one to infinite" matches. if your text has two or more urls, you're allowing a match of **ALL** the text between those two urls. or even two `/` will do it: `foo http://example.com/ this is some filler text with a . and /"` will capture the "this is some filler text"

Comment: See [What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extract URLs from text in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910912/extract-urls-from-text-in-php)

Comment: Do you want to **validate** or just want to **extract** it?

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in **extracting** the url instead of **validating** it then try below regex:

```
\bhttps?:\/\/[^\s]*
```

Here is [online demo](http://regex101.com/r/cL3zD4/3)

sample code:

```
$re = "/\\bhttps?:\\/\\/[^\\s]*/im";
$str = "http://www.regex101.com https://www.stachoverflow.com";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```