# Extracting url from string php

Tags: php

I am trying to extract URL out of a string. The format of the string will be:

```
some text! some numbers http://linktoimage.com/image
```

I found this post earlier [Extract URLs from text in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910912/extract-urls-from-text-in-php)

and I think this solution mentioned there could work:

```
<?php
$string = "this is my friend's website http://example.com I think it is coll";
echo explode(' ',strstr($string,'http://'))[0]; //"prints" http://example.com
```

However I do not understand what it actually does. Would someone mind explaining this to me to me ?

Comment: Have you looked up the functions you are using in the official documentation or elsewhere on the web? Contrary to popular believe Stack Overflow is not a community driven google result fetcher.

Answer (score -1):

You have this string:

> this is my friend's website http://example.com I think it is coll

`strstr($string,'http://')` will return

> http://example.com I think it is coll

`explode(' ', ...)` then will split this resulting string at the space character resulting in

```
array(
  0 => 'http://example.com',
  1 => 'I',
  2 => 'think',
  3 => 'it',
  4 => 'is',
  5 => 'coll'
)
```

and finally `[0]` returns the first item of this array, which is:

> http://example.com

Further reading:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: What if url is https or written without http ?

Comment: Then it is not matched. The code you presented just does a simple string matching. If there is no `http://` in the string, it doesn't match. I could be useful to use regular expressions for that as suggested in the question you were referring to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910912/extract-urls-from-text-in-php