# php regex operation for url and # value detection

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I want to make all the URL occurrence in text string as link.
When I tried

`preg_match($reg_exUrl, $text, $url) 
echo preg_replace($reg_exUrl1, '<a href="'.$url[0].'" rel="nofollow">'.$url[0].'</a>', $text);`

it has replaced first match URL at all the places.

Also following regex expression was not able to detect URL which ar starting with www.

```
$reg_exUrl1 = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";

$text = "The text you want to filter goes here. http://www.google.com data which in the http://www.apple.com";

if( preg_match($reg_exUrl, $text, $url)){
 echo preg_replace($reg_exUrl1, '<a href="'.$url[0].'" rel="nofollow">'.$url[0].'</a>', $text);
   // if no URLs in the text just return the text

}else {
    echo "IN Else #$".$text;
 }
```

This is the code for # value detection in string.

$text= "This is a detection of a #tag values in the text. any #special values with #hash will be shown as link";

```
$reg_exUrl ="/#\w+/";
if( preg_match($reg_exUrl1, $text, $url)){
    echo preg_replace($reg_exUrl1, '<a href="'.$url[0].'"     rel="nofollow">'.$url[0].'</a>', $text);
}else {
  echo "not Matched".$text;
```

}

Comment: Instead of posting new questions why don't you search first ?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910912/extract-urls-from-text-in-php

Comment: @PedroLobito, I have already googled it and found the link which you have posted , but if you try any of those given solution, it is not giving desired output.

That's the reason i raise the question again.

Comment: @PedroLobito if you check care fully my quetion if little bit diffrent than what you have suggested.
My problem was i am not able to replace all url,
one url detect will work fine in the code which i have pested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this

```
$reg_exUrl1 = "~(http|https|ftp|ftps)://[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(/S*)?~";

$text = "The text you want to filter goes here. http://www.google.com data which in the http://www.apple.com";

if( preg_match($reg_exUrl1, $text, $url)){
 echo preg_replace($reg_exUrl1, '<a href="$0" rel="nofollow">$0</a>', $text);
   // if no URLs in the text just return the text

}else {
    echo "IN Else #$".$text;
 }
```

> UPDATE

```
$reg_exUrl ="/#\w+/";
if( preg_match($reg_exUrl, $text, $url)){
   echo preg_replace($reg_exUrl, '<a href="$0" rel="nofollow">$0</a>', $text);
}else {
  echo "not Matched".$text;
```

Comment: not working.
also it is replacing first match url to every where.

Comment: @Mam Programmer, it worked.

Comment: I need one more favour can you tell me same for the # value detection.
and replace all #value values with a link

Comment: can you paste any sample code?

Comment: sure, just a second i will add it into question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90960/discussion-between-mitul-maheshwari-and-man-programmer).

Comment: great, it's working cheers.

Comment: still the last thing remain was the URL detection with which start with www.
I want to detect all kind of URL whether they start from HTTP or www.