# PHP Check if textbox contains a link

Tags: javascript, php, string, codeigniter, variables

I want to know if it is possible to check if a textbox contains any link. And if it is possible to select that link out of the field.

I tried it like this, but the problem is that i can't select the whole link and the query is very imprecise.

```
$a = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing www.loremipsum.com/asd/fgh/jkl elitr, sed diam ';

                if (strpos($a, 'www.') !== false) {
                    echo 'true';
                }
```

So again for explanation:

I have a text field which can contain a comment but also links. I need to select the correct link out of this field and safe it seperatly in a variable.

I don't want you to code my code but it would be great if anyone know a function or a method to realize this.

Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910912/extract-urls-from-text-in-php

Comment: Try using a regular expression like the top voted answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809401/what-is-a-good-regular-expression-to-match-a-url along with `preg_match` or `preg_match_all` to retrieve the URL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract URLs from text in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910912/extract-urls-from-text-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a regex that matches www.whatever https://regex101.com/r/rdOKQB/1/

```
<?php

$string = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing www.loremipsum.com/asd/fgh/jkl elitr, sed diam ';
$regex= '#www\.\S+#';

preg_match_all($regex,$string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Which outputs : `www.loremipsum.com/asd/fgh/jkl`
See it here: https://3v4l.org/4t2oV

You might want another regex testing for http:// or https:// instead/too? https://regex101.com/r/rdOKQB/2

```
#https?:\/\/\S+#
```

Comment: wow, thank you it really works. but how can i output only the link and not the whole array?

Comment: thank you. i solved it with a for-loop. because it can be more than one link. But isn't the first [0] unnecessary?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of strpos you can use strstr which returns next word.