# is that possible if i have input some url in input field then get posted/result as custom text in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, url, input, text

I'm making a form with bootstrap and codeigniter 3, and I want the results of my form like "tester 1" http://prntscr.com/m6vz1w

but I don't want to enter the code and URL in my input field like this http://prntscr.com/m6w10y

I want output like "tester 1" http://prntscr.com/m6vz1w and 
input field like this http://prntscr.com/m6w6fa 
so I just entered the url in input field and automatically converted the URL into "this is a link" to the page like "tester 1" http://prntscr.com/m6vz1w

my form view
http://prntscr.com/m6wafx

my controller
http://prntscr.com/m6watv

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract URLs from text in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910912/extract-urls-from-text-in-php)

Comment: Add code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Don´t do this:

```
redirect('c_admin/toagenda');
```

Do this (call the function that is showing your view):

```
$this->function();
```

Set error message, like:

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('required', 'This is required');
$this->form_validation->set_message('trim', 'This is trimed');
```

On your view to show error, do:

```
<span class="text-danger"><?=form_error('taggal')?></span>
<span class="text-danger"><?=form_error('judul')?></span>
<span class="text-danger"><?=form_error('keterangan')?></span>
```