# Don Crawler , get a Javascript attribute of a div onClick

Tags: php, laravel, domcrawler

I want to loop the div - my-node-div ,
and get the LINK that is a javascript onclick property THAT IS IN MY DIV that I am looping .

I have this structure -

```
<div id="container">
<div class="my-node-div" onclick="window.location='https://www.website1.com'">
<h1>Title One</h1>
</div>

<div class="my-node-div" onclick="window.location='https://www.website2.com'">
<h1>Title Two</h1>
</div>

<div class="my-node-div" onclick="window.location='https://www.website3.com'">
<h1>Title Three</h1>
</div>
</container>
```

so I would make something like that -

```
 $html    = $client->request('GET', $url_of_website);
                $crawler = new Crawler();
                $crawler->filter('div#container > div.my-node-div')->each(
                   function (Crawler $node, $index) use ($refer) {
                      // GET THE TEXT  
                     $H1 =  $node->filter('h1')->text();
                      // HOW COULD i GET THE window.location= WEBSITE ?
                     $LINK = ?
               });
         }
```

how could I get this javascript link that is in my div ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the attribute from a node, you'll use the `extract`[1] method on the `$node`.

```php
$crawler = new Crawler($html);
$links = $crawler->filter('div#container > div.my-node-div')
    ->each(function(Crawler $node) {
        return $node->extract(['onclick']);
    });
```

Now `$links` will contain an array of whatever's in that nodes `onclick` attribute.

```php
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 'window.location=\'https://www.website1.com\'',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 'window.location=\'https://www.website2.com\'',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 'window.location=\'https://www.website3.com\'',
  ),
)
```

Then you'll have to parse out the link from there, maybe try [Extract URLs from text in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910912/extract-urls-from-text-in-php) for some ideas.

1. [Accessing Node Values](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html#accessing-node-values)